# Pins are not showing up after publishing to app store

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When testing and debugging I used my debugging API key, now I have moved over to my publish API key and published the app.

The map loads and GPS location is shown (indicating the API key is correct) however the pins (annotations) are not showing. I am also getting the **below error:**

```
08-12 15:50:42.315: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11478): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I have checked and I have this:

[image]

So I thought everything would be okay.

Also getting this error:

```
08-12 15:50:42.315: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11478): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-12 15:50:42.325: E/log_tag(11478): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-12 15:50:42.325: E/log_tag(11478): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
08-12 15:50:42.325: E/log_tag(11478): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I have tried generating new keys and tracing the JSON that is downloaded and all seems good.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the network on the main thread. Don't do that, it clogs up your threads.

See: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I am not doing this intentionally - how can I stop this from happening? I havent actually said for it to use the main thread.

Comment: If you read the link I sent you theres all kinds of options. Mainly you want to put your network interactions on a new thread.